# Generate new date(week) columns the dplyr-way so that SQL can translate properly

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table in a MS SQL Server database. This table has a datetime column with observations like `2020-10-21 00:00:00` and i want to generate two new columns from this datetime observations with `dplyr`namely `current_calendar_week` and `week_of_that_specific_date`

The usually way, aside from databases, would be:

```
tibble(date=as_datetime("2020-10-21 00:00:00")) %>%
mutate(`current_week` = isoweek(Sys.Date()), `specific_week` = isoweek(date))
```

But these function `isoweek()` (from lubridate) cannot be translated to SQL properly. So my question is how would i correctly mutate these new columns with dplyr so that there is an equivalent SQL translation?

Comment: You can do this in the database, but you are specifically asking to do this in R.  I removed the SQL and database tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DATE_PART` and inline sql with `dplyr::sql()`

```r
tibble(date = as_datetime("2020-10-21 00:00:00")) %>%
mutate(`current_week` = dplyr::sql(DATE_PART('week', current_date)),
       `specific_week` = dplyr::sql(DATE_PART('week',  date)))
```